# Page elements shifting up on toggle click

Tags: css, safari, toggle, slideshow

In Safari (all other browsers don't have this problem) when I click to toggle my content, all the elements on the page shift to the top. I've worked out that it's conflicting with RefineSlide, as when I remove the CSS for that slideshow, the issue goes away. I've narrowed it down to the two sections in the CSS that are affecting the toggle click:

```
.rs-slider > li {
list-style: none;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
opacity: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 -100% 0 0;
padding: 0;
float: left;
position: relative;
}

.rs-thumb-wrap > a {
display: block;
float: left;
position: relative;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

What should I change to get the toggling to not shift upwards in Safari?

Comment: It's the -100% margin that's the issue. I've changed it to zero but now the slideshow is super long in height. Just playing around with the height value now.

Comment: Can you create sample for us using http://jsfiddle.net?